# Validating the Numerical Order of 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays

So, I have a 2D array with columns that are supposed to be sorted in numerical order.  However, I want to make sure that the user's input conforms to this rule.  This piece of code was my attempt to ensure that the user input is valid.

```
for (int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < map.length - 1; i++) {
        if (map[i][j] != null && map[i + 1][j] != null) {
            if (x[i][j] > x[i + 1][j]) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine for the first column, but, when it loops into the top of the second column, an IllegalArgumentException is thrown because the first number in the second column will often be less than the last number in the first column.  However, since the columns are ordered in numeric order, this is rather expected behavior.  So, my question is this: Is there a better way to check that the next number in a column is always greater the current number and to do this for each column.  As mentioned before, my current attempts at this throws exceptions.

Here is a table of elements inputted into the program.  The last element is where the exception is thrown (9B):

```
 1A XXX
 2A XXX
 2A XXX
 3A XXX
XXX XXX
 9A  9B
10A
11A
12A
13A
20A
```

Comment: The code looks fine. I don't think this code will throw an exception in the scenario you have described. Can you provide the map values that will throw an exception?

Comment: The reason you give for an IllegalArgumentException being thrown is incorrect: there is no comparison of elements between columns.

Comment: can you give an example of your 2D array at leas a 3x3 to see how the sorting is being made, by rows or by column

Comment: @user3735278 I don't understand the example. Just add it as a table in your question (edit it)

Comment: What kind of guessing game are you playing?

Comment: Your i/p array isn't sorted column wise I think that's why you are getting exception, otherwise the code is fine.

Comment: So you aren't able to produce a few lines of Java that show how this array is declared and initialized? Are you *really* suggesting that we guess what these unintelligible characters mean?

Comment: I edited my question.  Sorry, I didn't see the initial comments at first.

Comment: You can't compare String values using <. - Also, I'm beginning to wonder about the snippet you've posted. What's this array `x` doing in there?

Comment: The "xxx" are ignored and the strings are stripped of their letters and parsed as ints.